# Draw formatted text inside a Table/Cell with Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am running Rails 3.0.1 with prawn-0.11.1.pre

I just did some basic tests to see if I can get Prawn to create a simple table that includes some formatted text:

```
data = ["Cell 1", formatted_text([{:text => "Cell 2"}])], 
       ["Cell 3","Cell 4"]
table(data)
render
```

The PDF renders like this

```
Cell 2
[Cell 1][      ]
[Cell 3][Cell 4]
```

(a nice table but with the text "Cell 2" outside the table)

My goal is to get the formatted text "Cell 2" inside Cell #2...

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`formatted_text` doesn't return formatted text, it renders it. So, when 
you call `formatted_text` while building your data for `table`, "Cell 2"
is rendered before the table and the cell at row 1 and column 2 is 
empty. I think you want to put at [Prawn::Table::Cell::Text](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.10.2/Prawn/Table/Cell/Text.html) object
where you have your `formatted_text` call. If `Prawn::Table::Cell::Text`
doesn't support everything you need then you'll probably have to make your
subclass of `Prawn::Table::Cell` and do it all by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... this is very frustrating... I am trying to understand how Prawn works and I hardly understand the documentation...

Comment: Could you please give me an extra help: When trying to create a simple Prawn::Table::Cell::Text object with the following code: Prawn::Table::Cell::Text.make(self, :content => "Cell 2") but I still got some errors (this time the error is "Content type not recognized: {:content=>"test"}". What would be the correct way of creating the object? Thanks again!

Comment: The second argument to `make` should be a "point", the `:content` and other options come after that. The docs for Prawn are a bit sparse. These examples might be of use, there are some uses of `Prawn::Table::Cell::Text` demonstrated: https://github.com/sandal/prawn/tree/stable/examples/

Comment: They are sparse indeed... I'll see what can I do with that ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At least in prawn 0.12, I can do:

```
table_data = 
  [[Prawn::Table::Cell::Text.new( pdf, [0,0], :content => "<b>Bold!</b>",
                                              :inline_format => true),
    Prawn::Table::Cell::Text.new( pdf, [0,0], :content => txt )
  ]]

  pdf.table(table_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style format with **cell style option** `inline_format`:

```
table [["Just <font size='18'>some</font> <b><i>inline</i></b>", "", ""],
         ["<color rgb='FF00FF'>styles</color> being applied here", "", ""]],
         :cell_style => { :inline_format => true }
```

See: https://github.com/practicingruby/prawn/blob/stable/manual/table/cell_text.rb#L28